# What skills can kill a hero under the effect of Shallow Grave?

Tags: dota-2, dota

In DotA and Dota 2 there is a hero called the Shadow Priest. His Shallow Grave skill is particularly tricksy, as it can render a hero immune to lethal damage for several seconds, effectively capable of preventing death multiple times over its duration. However, this ability does have a soft spot, it only protects heroes from LETHAL DAMAGE. It does NOT protect against instant death effects such as Axe's Ultimate skill.  
*Other than Axe's Ultimate, what other instant death effects does Shallow Grave fail to protect you from?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axe's Culling Blade is the only ability that kills through Shallow Grave. Techies is also capable of killing themselves when under the effect of Shallow Grave by using Suicide. The Shallow Grave ability is also not able to be purged, so there is zero worry other than that.

Some spells will poison/affect you for longer than the 5 seconds that Shallow Grave lasts and thus may kill you as the effect ends if you're not careful.

Comment: Does Borrowed Time also shares the same property as Shallow Grave? Should I make another separate question about it?

Comment: @MegaNairda Borrowed time triggers when you take damage that puts you under 400 HP. So anything that does more than that much damage in one go can kill you. After it's triggered, though, it's the same as Shallow Grave, only Culling Blade will kill you.

Comment: You can also suicide with Bloodstone while shallow graved

Answer (score -2):

Other than Axe's ulti, ancient apparition's ulti can also kill you if you reach the break point under shallow grave.

Comment: That's not true.